# Errors about linking but I have already linked that library

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

There are some errors appear about linking a library but I have linked that library and it was working before but after doing Clear Solution in visual studio 2015, that link problem happened.
I have linked all required libs files and it is assumed that this problem doesn't occur.

I have linked the following Libs file:

- wxmsw31u_core.lib, wxbase31u.lib, wxtiff.lib, wxjpeg.lib, wxpng.lib,
  wxzlib.lib, libcurl.lib, ws2_32.lib, Wldap32.lib, comctl32.lib, rpcrt4.lib.

Also the path of lib files:
`wxWidgets_v3.1.1\lib\x86\vc_lib`.

[image]

**How can I resolve that problem, what is that I have missed?**

Comment: If you have changed VS version then re-compile wxWidgets after removing previous VS-compiled files.

Comment: @Ripi2: I haven't changed the version of visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Try Adding  wxAdvanced library
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_task_bar_icon.html

Comment: I think that library in `wxmsw31u_core.lib` or `wxbase31u.lib` right?

Comment: It should be `wxmsw31u_adv.lib`

Comment: Please put the library file name (.lib) in your answer to accept your answer as the best answer.